# I have erosion issues wirth gravel road

Tags: driveway

I have major erosion issues with millings road. My property is sloped . Needed advice for installing either channel drains with existing road or go with blacktop.

Comment: The question is quite broad and therefore not a good fit for our Q&A format. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and see the [help pages](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more.

Comment: Yes, this question is awfully, awfully light to be answerable. Obviously there's a whole ton of stuff you are seeing "in your mind's eye" or with your actual eyes, and you think your question makes it obvious, but it does not.

Comment: PLease explain what a "millings" road is.   BTW, in general the way to eliminate erosion on a dirt/sand/gravel/stone road is to make it well-crowned.

Comment: A photo of the area you have concerns about would be helpful. Here in the Pacific Northwest we install drains across the road at bends, one trick I learned years ago after packing a crushed rock road sprinkle Portland cement on the rock (we use a grass seed spreader then a broom to pull the cement into the cracks this really strengthens the holding power of the rock, it doesn’t take much for most of the road way. the wash out areas may need 2-3x as much cement but it helps reduce washouts.

Comment: Millings are recycled blacktop.

Comment: These are pics of main driveway.